# How to reauthenticate a user using Google Oauth2

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Here's my problem.  I have a Google Plus link on a page with a custom image.  The URL is

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=' .
>   Zend_Registry::get('config')->googlePlus->client_id . '&redirect_uri='
>   . urlencode($strRedirectUrl) .
>   '&access_type=offline&response_type=code&scope=' .
>   urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login') . '&' .
>   urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me')

The client ID and redirect are passed in dynamically.  (This link is generated by a PHP function.)

The user clicks a link and authenticates with Google.  Now I need to log them into my app.  The only thing that seems to come back from the server is the authentication code.  I somehow need to have a `Google_Client` that I can get the user info on.  Thing is when I build up the client to meet all of Google's requirements, I get an issue that I'm trying to reuse the code.  I think I've figured a work around for that.

What happens, though, is a get a `redirect_uri_mismatch`.  Extensive Googling says this is because the URI is not in my developer console.  Yet it is.  I've quadruple checked it and it is exactly the same.  There are no special ports or trailing slashes or anything.  So I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

Is it because I pass in a redirect_uri in the above link and then specify one below?  I did notice that if I make the two redirect_uris the same, the redirect_uri error goes away, but then I get an error that the code has already been redeemed.  I guess because its cycling back over where it was before.  I can't have the two be the same anyway, because I need different ones to route the browser through my code.

(All of the Zend_Registry values below have been confirmed.  This function returns a string, the necessary API key.)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Web Application');
$client->setClientId(Zend_Registry::get('config')->googlePlus->client_id);
$client->setDeveloperKey(Zend_Registry::get('config')->googlePlus->serverKey);
$client->setClientSecret(Zend_Registry::get('config')->googlePlus->secret);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://test.XXX.com/login/social/network/google');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force'); # this line is important when you revoke permission from your app, it will prompt google approval dialogue box forcefully to user to grand offline access
$client->getRefreshToken();

$plus = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken())
 {
     $userinfo = $plus->userinfo;
     die(print_r($userinfo->get()));

 }
```

I don't like the way this is structured, since I've already authenticated with Google when the user filled in their credentials in the popup window.  But I don't see any way around it.  I'm open to any and all suggestions.  This is my first time working with this API and I have to say the documentation absolutely sucks.

Comment: If you look at the "request details" dropdown on the error page, does the `redirect_uri` value match exactly one of the apps configured redirect_uris? Character for character, including protocol, ports, following slash, etc.

Comment: I don't get the Google error page with the request details.  By that point in the cycle, Zend has intercepted the call and throws the Google exception as its own -- without the request details.

Comment: But what is in the code is exactly, character for character, what's in the dev console, to answer your question.  Unless something is getting rewritten, which I don't know how to see since Zend is in the mix by then.

Comment: One thing that would be a big help is knowing EXACTLY what link I need users to click on to pop up the auth window.  Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scopes need to be separated by a space. You have added 
 . '&' .

And that means the second scope is an invalid key as & is a special character.

If you are not aware, you may find Oauthplayground quite useful in trying various requests.
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: That wasn't my problem (yet).  I never got that far, but it's good to know and good info for other people, so I accepted your answer even though it didn't directly pertain to my issue.

Comment: We can try to help debug.  If this somewhere where we can see the page (and the links)? Also do you need plus.login scope? Do you need Google+ social features? If not, just go with Google sign-in to simplify user experience https://developers.google.com/identity/  (see Google sign-in web)